# Is docker for windows running linux container in virtualbox?

Tags: windows, docker

I installed the latest docker for windows from website.

[image]

there is no virtualbox installed. How windows run a linux container in my computer ? Is have a buildin linux kernel in windows?

Comment: and I want execute docker command in container. My emacs work on container.How I can do this? in the past I mount the docker daemon socks file in virtualbox to container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses HyperV in newer releases. VirtualBox was used by docker-machine which is part of docker-toolkit.

Inside of the VM, there is a Linux kernel in a [linuxkit](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit) based OS that is part of the moby project.

Connecting to the docker socket on Windows is described in this FAQ: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api